# Include the helpers for one resource inside the views for another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to use some methods from `properties_helper.rb` inside a view for `reports` resource (i.e. use the helpers for one resource inside the views for another).

I tried this

```
# app/views/reports/show.html.erb

<% include PropertiesHelper %>
```

but I get this error

```
NoMethodError in Reports#show
Showing show.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `include' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000011530>
```

I'm surprised it didn't work.

Comment: What rails version are you running? 

[By default](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b5db73076914e7103466bd76bec785cbcfe88875/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb#L12), you can use the methods from others helpers in any view.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to include the `PropertiesHelper` in your view. Most important thing is creating helpers for appropriate views or if it is to be global, then create helper methods in `ApplicationHelper` from which all other helpers inherit.